# Как принять геолакацию от пользователя pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telebot, геолокация

Надо, чтобы, когда пользователь отправлял геолокацию, бот её записывал в БД и отмечал на пользовательской карте. Бот нужен для того, чтобы люди, например, отмечали где накидан мусор, а металоприемники могли за ним приехать.

Comment: Ваш код где? что не получается?

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, чтовы
пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста,
отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при 
решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
import telebot

# Инициализация бота
bot = telebot.TeleBot('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN')

# Обработчик сообщений с геолокацией
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['location'])
def handle_location(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    latitude = message.location.latitude
    longitude = message.location.longitude
    timestamp = message.date

    # Сохранение данных о геолокации в БД
    save_location_to_db(user_id, latitude, longitude, timestamp)

    # Отметка на карте
    add_marker_to_map(latitude, longitude)

    # Отправка пользователю сообщения с подтверждением
    bot.send_message(user_id, "Геолокация сохранена и отмечена на карте!")

# Запуск бота
bot.polling()
```

Comment: спасибо буду пробовать, а вопрос в встроеную бд будет сохранять бот инфу?

Comment: Да, должен сохранять так как  save_location_to_db(user_id, latitude, longitude, timestamp)

Comment: 1) Не используйте gpt для генерации ответов 2) Не делайте работу за тех, кто её даже не пытался сделать сам.